# Unable to create section border in tableview and i want to represent the ui as per the attached image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sections

[image]

how  to create section border in tableview  and i want to represent the ui as per the attached image ? i  displayed spaces between sections but cannot set the border line for section.

Comment: Create custom header view and add 1 pixel height of `UIImageView` with that gray color.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add and import

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

After that follow below steps

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  UIView  *section = [[UIView alloc]init];
  section.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableview.frame.size.width, height);
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"imageName"]];
  imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, YOUR_WIDTH, YOUR_HEIGHT); //set your frame
  [section addSubview:imageView];     

  labelSection = [[UILabel alloc]init];
  labelSection.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
  labelSection.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, tableview.frame.size.width, 20); 
  [labelSection setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [labelSection setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
  NSString *name = @"section title";
  labelSection.text = name;
  [labelSection setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  [section addSubview:labelSection];


  section.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
  section.layer.cornerRadius =  1.0f;
  section.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
  section.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;  

  return section;
}
```

If you want to set row height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 44;  //It default size.If you want to change to other size you can change.
    //OR
 // return 90; //Set to your needed size
}
```

Comment: wont it add borders to all cells instead of sections?